# Is there a way to check if a force is being applied to an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, game-physics

I have an object that can move dynamically in any direction. I want to pull it in a set direction, at a constant speed, but only if it's not moving in the general pull direction (not necessarily parallel). In other words, if it's moving towards me, I don't need to pull it.

My question then is; is there a way to check if this object is moving in this general pull direction?

Comment: What do you mean "have that force within its velocity vector"? Forces aren't "within" velocity vectors. They aren't even measured in the same units... Are you saying you need to add velocity to a vector until its has at least some amount of velocity in a certain direction?

Comment: @Ruzihm Sorry, you’re right, I’ll edit my question. What I mean is if the velocity vector of the object is C, the constant velocity is B, and A is the difference, how do I find if the equation A + B = C exists? Is that clearer?

Comment: Basic math, ```C - (A + B) == 0```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dot product between the direction the "pull" force is applying and the current velocity is greater than 1, then the velocity is going in the direction of the pull.

```
Vector3 pullDirection;
Vector3 currentVelocity;

bool isMovingInPullDirection = Vector3.Dot(pullDirection, currentVelocity) > 0;
```

Comment: This works until I apply a force, say perpendicular to the constant velocity. Then the check fails.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the force is, as your clarification suggests, only the velocity of the object. If the constant velocity of the object is (1,0,0) and the object is moving at (1,0,0) and you apply a force of (0,0,1)  then the velocity becomes something like (1,0,0.5) and it returns true as it should, correct?

Comment: Hmm, I guess my clarification was wrong then lol. Well, think of it this way; gravity is the constant velocity and the object is a spaceship capable of moving in any direction. Moving the spaceship in any direction should not alter the gravity, but the gravity should always be there. I just need to know how to determine if it IS there.

Comment: @Bishop Gravity isnt a velocity but I think I understand what you're getting at. Tried reframing the question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble explaining my question lol. My last analogy wasn't quite right. The force has to stop when the object is moving towards the source (in this case, gravity's source). I rephrased my question a little. Didn't see that you did until I was done. Thanks for all the help either way.